# Blazor 8 rendering error causes DOM elements to disappear

Tags: blazor, rendering, blazor-webassembly

I have a website I've been upgrading from Blazor 7 to 8. It was a Blazor Wasm site, now to be Auto rendered where appropriate (and left static where possible). All projects have been recreated and the new Web Template used.  It uses Auto render mode on several pages. All was going well until yesterday (9/10 January).  I now get have pages which are unchanged and worked fine 2 days but now don't render parts of the page or don't run events (button onClick).  Even a  static home page, with an auto component included in the layout now has missing parts.  These pages worked 2 days ago without change.

The console shows:

```
blazor.web.js:1  Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'setStartBefore' on 'Range': the given Node has no parent.
    at q (https://localhost:7197/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:20110)
    at yi (https://localhost:7197/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:168298)
    at wi (https://localhost:7197/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:170259)
    at yi (https://localhost:7197/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:167974)
    at wi (https://localhost:7197/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:170259)
    at yi (https://localhost:7197/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:167974)
    at vi (https://localhost:7197/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:166291)
    at https://localhost:7197/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:176564
    at Object.write (https://localhost:7197/_framework/blazor.web.js:1:174880)
```

I also note there was a windows update at the same time.
This is blocking all dev on the site as the most basic pages no longer work.
Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: Clean the browser cache and try again? just like what you said, your code didn't change but not working all of a sudden....

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug. Microsoft fixed this problem in .Net 8.0.2.

The relevant issue ticket is https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52126 if you're interested.